# CSS not loading after server change - Social Engine

Tags: css, server, socialengine

Hey I am working on a Client's website that is built using Social engine , there is one weired issue I am facing.

Let me explain :

The website was working fine at original url let say www.abc.com , but as soon as I changed the url and tried to access the website from IP address associated with it, it was still working but just the home page and all other pages aren't loading some CSS/JS files .

I tried to move everything to my local server , but that couldnt help either and same issue was there at local server.

please see the image http://prntscr.com/860xmq

I am trying to fix it from last week but no luck please advice me how I can fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are URLs being rewritten? In that case you need to copy over the server configuration as well. Apache is normally configured using `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` and other files, for example. URLs do not always point to actual locations on a server.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the problem**

From the Screenshot it is clear that few of the `.css` and `.js` are not found i.e., it is not pointing to exact path.

**How to fix it**

Make sure that you are pointing it to correct location.

**Note :**

Make sure that you have used the correct path i.e.,

For CSS :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/yourcssfile.css">
```

and not something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="localhost/yourprojectfolder/css/yourcssfile.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use PHP, then you can add this :

```
<?php
$base_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])=="\\"?"":dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']))."/";
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url; ?>css/yourcssfile.css">
```

so when you change your server name/domain it will adjust automatically.